# How do you put padding/margin around the content of the drawer in antd?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

It is showing up like this for me.

[image]

How do I make the content have padding, without having to write custom CSS and use the `className` property? My drawer essentially looks like this:

```
<Drawer
  closable
  visible
  width={400}
  placement="right"
  title="Create"
  >
  <Form
    layout="vertical"
  >
    <Form.Item name="name" label="Name">
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [antd Grid](https://ant.design/components/grid/) to wrap your drawer content inside a row-col wrapper. To define the padding you can use the `gutter` property of row.

There is already and example for that on the antd [drawer demo page](https://ant.design/components/drawer/#components-drawer-demo-form-in-drawer).